# Angular 2 (11) Is there a way to implement Partial Component similar to Microsoft Razor can with partial views?

Tags: angular, razor, master-detail, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my Angular 11 application it would be especially nice to have partial HTML-only templates that a component can bind to for data grids and a few other purposes.  I don't believe Angular supports this concept without one full component routing to another full component.

Essentially I am interested in a more efficient way to manage all my Master/Detail views.  I would prefer a scenario where:

master.component.ts / master.component.html can use subviews located in, say, view1.component.html, view2.component.html, viewn.component.html while not having to have the subview's component.ts to need to have its context passed in.

Perhaps this isn't part of Angular's best practice; perhaps it should be.

Comment: you do not always need routing, you can conditionally include one view component or other. you need to create those view components though and pass the input data

Comment: That's what I thought.   It's unfortunate to have to pass in significant amounts of data.   While I have many object arrays and view state parameters already available on the Master component, seems like I could use a reusable HTML stub that contains only the grid layout that is common to all Detail views.

Comment: if you already have object arrays, it does not cost anything to pass this data, if not, view can load it as well - say on route "/products/123", the master component can retrieve product data and view - the array of related data.